# Form method and lightbox (or alternative)

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, lightbox

I've been looking over [an older post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16286967/deciding-between-form-confirmation-methods) trying to work out a solution for showing the confirmation PHP in a lightbox.

As my knowledge on javascript and ajax is close to zero - well, it IS zero - I'm hoping someone might elaborate.

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php">
```

Is the basic form method. Would I be able to use something like [Tinybox2](http://sandbox.scriptiny.com/tinybox2/) and simply add

```
TINY.box.show({url:'submit.php',post:'id=16',width:200,height:100,opacity:20,topsplit:3})
```

to the action, rather than a php?

Cheers, Trin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use TinyBox, you need to serialize your form before you post it. One of the fastest and nonpainful way to do this to use jQuery (Just add reference if you haven't done this.)

```
TINY.box.show({url: $("form").prop("action"), post:$('form').serialize(),width:200,height:100,opacity:20,topsplit:3})
```

First one grabs the "action" url from your form, and the second method makes your form to be posted with TinyBox.

This code should display a tinybox when user submits the form:

```
$("form").submit(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    TINY.box.show({
        url: $("form").prop("action"), 
        post: $('form').serialize(),
        width:200,
        height:100,
        opacity:20,
        topsplit:3
    });
    return;
});
```

Just put this inside

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
   // Here.
}
</script>
```

block.

Comment: Does that mean, that you would add the above code like

    <form method="post" action="TINY.box.show({url: $("form").prop("action"), post:$('form').serialize(),width:200,height:100,opacity:20,topsplit:3})">

Or somewhere else?

Comment: That doesn't work if you add that to action; but if you want to display a lightbox when the submits the form (e.g: by pressing a button), this can be achieved and I can add this to my answer.

Comment: That would be highly appreciated!

Comment: Aweomse, thanks for the suggestions. I'd play around with it for a while.

Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem. If this doesn't work, I can still suggest an alternative way to post your form but code will be slightly different and maybe longer.